# radio button value not passed to php function

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble passing radio button values to a function. The values are being generated. I echoed both $company_id and $_POST['package'] on the page and both echo correctly. Below, I have provided the code both for the tecnoDB function select_service which I am trying to instantiate as well as the actual code from the page where the radio buttons are. I am not using any javascript in the code.

HERE IS THE page where the radio buttons are:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
if (!array_key_exists("user", $_SESSION)) {
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}
require_once("Includes/tecnoDB.php");
$company_id = tecnoDB::getInstance()->get_company_id_by_name($_SESSION['user']);


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == [$_POST]){
  if (array_key_exists("contratar", $_POST)){
    require_once("Includes/tecnoDB.php");
    tecnoDB::getInstance()->select_service($company_id, $_POST['package']);
    header("Location: companyControlPanel.php");
}
}
?>

    <form name="selection" action="" method="POST">
        <ul>
            <li>Recruiter Lite <input type="radio" name="package" value="1"  /></li>
            <li>Recruiter Plus <input type="radio" name="package" value="2"  /></li>
            <li>Premium <input type="radio" name="package" value="3"  /></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" name="contratar" value="Contratar Servicio" />
    </form>
```

HERE is the function for select_service that I am trying to instantiate

```
public function select_service($company_id, $package){
$company_id = $this->real_escape_string($company_id);
$package = $this->real_escape_string($package);
$this->query("UPDATE company SET service = '" . $package . "' WHERE id = '" . $company_id . "'");
}
```

Really not sure why the function is not being instantiated when the parameters are in existence. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong in your code to make sure the request method is POST:

```
 <?php
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == [$_POST]){
```

should be

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
```

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` contains a string with the request method. This can be e.g. GET or POST, but it'll never equal `$_POST`. You can read more about the `$_SERVER` superglobal in the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: works perfect with what you said. I appreciate it. I knew I had to be missing something simple. fresh eyes always work.